# Adverb relative clause or nominal relative clause?

Tags: sentence-construction, relative-clauses, relative-adverbs

> #1.It never snows where I live.

I can't understand a structure of the sentence above. I don't now whether it is an *adverb relative clause* or a *nominal relative clause*. Whatever it is, I think it needs something before *where clause* ; an antecedent or a preposition. Otherwise, Would *'where clause'* function itself an adverb in the sentence?

Or Do I have to understand the structure of the sentence like the following.

> #2.Where I live, It never snows.
>
> #3.When I had lived, It never snowed.

So, do all # 1,2 and 3 have the same structure?

Comment: Adverbial clause of place : My son told me another fight broke out where he eats lunch at school.

Comment: An adjunct of place, but a preposition phrase, not a clause.

Comment: Reference : https://www.docdroid.net/t5kj/fused-relatives-pdf

Comment: That's a useful reference, @bak1936

Comment: serve ; to work or perform duties for a person, an organization, a country, etc/ work ;  to function; to operate.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is fine as is. “Where I live” is an adverbial clause. It modifies the verb “snows” and answers the question “where”. I wouldn’t call it a “relative” clause, though.

Comment: one more question! If where clause answers the question "where", which question could exist? I think the answer of *where I live* isn't common. I don't still understand that part of your answer.

Comment: Verb-modifying adverbials typically answer where, when, why, or how. (Usually—not always.)

Comment: I know 5W-H questions. but Answering a question in *where, when, why or how* have been difficult to find in google so far. Please, show me some supporting evidences. Also, I think Verb-modifying adverbials have nothing to do with question. I don't know what it is.

Comment: @bak1936 What Marc is saying is right, though I would call "where I live" not a clause but a PP in a fused relative construction. Whichever analysis is preferred, "where I live" is functioning as an adjunct in clause structure, i.e. a modifier in the VP "never snows". Note that 'adjunct' is a better term than adverbial.

Answer (score 1):

> *It never snows* [*where I live*].

Yes: it's a 'fused' relative construction (your nominal relative) in which "where" is a preposition, thus *where I live* is a preposition phrase.

It has a paraphrase containing noun + integrated relative: *It never snows in the place where I live*, where the expression "where I live" is clearly a relative clause modifying "place".

The 'fusion' involves the preposition "where", which simultaneously serves as head of the noun phrase and adjunct of place in the relative clause.

Comment: Thanks Billj always!! you make me study harder, but sometimes I couldn't find the information in your answer.

Comment: I understand a little, but I don't know what *head of the noun phrase* means. I just know a little the concept of AP, NP and VP. In where clause, It is difficult for me to understand what the head become.

Comment: and Is it right that *where* is preposition? Do you mean *where* functions preposition for NRC is NP?

Comment: @bak1936 Yes, in "It never snows [where I live]", "where" is a preposition, so the bracketed element is a preposition phrase, not a clause. Think of "where" as meaning "in the place", which clearly is a preposition phrase whose head word is the preposition "in".

Comment: Thanks!! PP's head is preposition.